# Securely sending data within local wifi

Tags: c#, .net, security, networking, encryption

What is a secure way of pairing a client and a server and ensuring that a request made has been from a client? My idea is to send a password with each request, but someone else on the network could sniff that data, even if it's encrypted. They can then resend that packet and the server would think the correct PC has sent it. Even sending a hash wouldn't work, since the attacker could just resend the hash.

The user will be running the server on one PC and the client will be another PC, but someone else could be on the same Wifi network. What's a good way of trying to secure this sort of connection or is this not even possible?

Comment: as with everything, just use SSL and most of the problem goes away.

Comment: Don't invent your own method, use SSL.

Comment: @MarcB To use SSL, do I have to pay for a certificate and then install that certificate on every user's machine? Can't a user just take that certificate and use it for their own products?

Comment: no. you install a certificate on the SERVER. ssl takes care of the rest. e.g. you don't have to buy an amazon.com certificate to be able to talk to the amazon.com website. and you don't HAVE to buy a cert. you can trivially generate your own, at the cost of getting "self-signed certificate" warnings in the clients.

Comment: @MarcB - Each user has two machines. One is the server, one is the client. So I suppose that means I install it on all the user's servers. When the user installs the program, will they need admin rights or can the certificate just be in a directory within the installation folder? The program is a WPF form, not a website (I've updated the tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSL with mutual authentication.

You don't need to pay for a certificate, you can be your own certificate authority and grant as many as you want.

Comment: @superwpf People pay for it because they want users from around the world to connect, so they pay commercial certificate authorities because their public keys are in most web browsers. If you are building your own app that you distribute, you can just embed the server's public key in your client.